# Java8 Optional fire one method if null , another if not null Best Approach

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I have A string and B string , app prefers A if not null, and call transformation method `changeA()`. However if A is null , it will use B and invoke method `changeB()` . Both transformation method return same object type `Result`. However one thing to note is that str B might null too, then if that case return null instead.

How do I approach this using optional and lambda expression in JDK.

I have the following codebase:

```
changeA(){
..
}

changeB(){
..
}

aMethod(){
    Optional<String> optA=Optional.ofNullable(a);
    Result result = optA.map( aStr -> this.changeA( aStr ) ).orElse( this.changeB( bStr ) );
}
```

This looks a bit weird cause the orElse method is using variable not within the scope of the lambda. May I know the best approach to this ?

---

Perhaps I should state why I chose Optional. I want my team's developer to understand that even though String A is preferred , it might be null and must be handled since the part of the code is sensitive . String B is used for legacy part of the records only. Hopefully this clarify my intention on this approach.

Comment: If it's not in scope, how is it using it?

Comment: it is within the class it is executing

Comment: hmm..you can say that

Comment: it's not that i can say that, it is. lambdas can only capture things that are in scope. that's a basic feature of lambdas.

Comment: i edited a bit on the code. if this is the case ? lambda can access them?

Comment: you don't need the `filter` step... I think the best approach is good old `if-else` or `?:` :)

Comment: Why try to over-complicate this into a single line for the sake of using a new, shiny thing? Just use if-else.

Comment: The primary use case for `Optional` is as a return value. That way developers are forced to handle the possible absence of a value, which should prevent NPEs. You, on the other hand, not only know that `a` can be null, but also have a method whose sole purpose is to handle that situation. Using an `Optional` here is somewhat pointless.

Comment: Isn't optional created to avoid the null checker and also pass a default value when value is absent?

Comment: I am going back to a simple if-else-then statement. Optional is kinda confusing to developer judging from comments here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To invoke `changeB` only when necessary you may use the following construct:

```
result = Optional.ofNullable(aStr).map(this::changeA).orElseGet(
          () -> Optional.ofNullable(bStr).map(this::changeB).orElse(null));
```

Note that you can do this without optionals at all:

```
result = aStr != null ? changeA(aStr) :
         bStr != null ? changeB(bStr) :
         null;
```

This is much shorter and generates cleaner bytecode.

An alternative functional way is to use the stream of suppliers:

```
Supplier<Result> aSupplier = () -> aStr == null ? null : changeA(aStr);
Supplier<Result> bSupplier = () -> bStr == null ? null : changeB(bStr);

result = Stream.of(aSupplier, bSupplier).map(Supplier::get)
               .filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

This approach is scalable: you may add more suppliers to the stream. You may replace `aStr == null ? null : changeA(aStr)` with `Optional.ofNullable(aStr).map(this::changeA).orElse(null)` if you don't like ternary operator.

Comment: what if `changeA` returns null; what's the behavior of `map` then? does it intuitively match OP's requirement spec (whatever it may be)? who knows :)

Comment: "This is much shorter and generates cleaner bytecode." +1

Comment: The stream of suppliers will still call all suppliers, which is probably not desired.

Comment: @DidierL, no. The streams are lazy. Test by yourself.

Comment: Indeed, right. It will only be a problem if the first called `changeX` method returns `null`.

Comment: @Didier L: if either of the `changeX` methods returns `null`, the stream solution will do exactly the same as the `Optional` variant. It’s the ternary operator variant which behaves differently. If that’s not intended, you can replace it by two subsequent `if` statements which will do.

Comment: I think the OP didn't notice that it doesn't match the description in his first paragraph. Well, if `changeA` may return `null` of course.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
Optional<String> optA = Optional.ofNullable(aStr).map(this::changeA);
Optional<String> optB = Optional.ofNullable(bStr).map(this::changeB);
result = optA.orElse(optB.orElse(null));
```

Comment: This approach would execute `changeB` even if it's unnecessary.

Comment: @TagirValeev - `Optional` just sucks. There's no apparent reason why it does what it does. And poor programmers think it's their fault not getting it.

Comment: @bayou.io, I would not say it sucks. It's just "of limited use" while many people try to use it everywhere.

Comment: @TagirValeev - its behavior is very complex and unintuitive. I'd rather use `if-else` than reading its fine prints.

Comment: @bayou.io For cases like this `Optional` is indeed complex and counterintuitive, and an ordinary conditional is preferable.